# How do I set up the architecture for a "big data" analysis project?

Tags: csv, hadoop, bigdata

A friend of mine and I are in our senior year and will be starting a senior project soon. We had the idea to do a data analysis and data visualization project for it. Our project involves reading a CSV file that is updated every 2 minutes, parsing that data, then storing it in a database. Once that data is stored we want to run some analysis on it and provide an API through which we could access that data to visualize in some way. Our end goal would be to build an Android app that displays some of the raw data from the CSV and the analysis in a user friendly format. I talked to another CS Major and he explained that I would need a few different servers to accomplish this: One for the storage, another for analysis, and another for some type of queue that would make sure things don't get screwy while we are doing scraping and analysis. The problem is, I don't really know where to start with this. I've done some work with a SQL database before and a PHP front end, but nothing with multiple servers. I've heard of tools to use with big data projects like Hadoop but i'm not exactly sure where it fits in. If someone could point me to a resource of some kind to explain, or explain themselves, how I would start to structure this kind of project, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have much experience with these things you'll probably want to look at projects like Cloudera. Specifically their [resources](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/resources.html) page has a nice set of videos and articles.

Another source of solid information (that I personally use) is by clicking on an Stack Overflow `tag` and selecting the `votes` option. Many good questions on a plethora of [big data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bigdata) topics ***already exists***.